# Аналог метода FileContentResult File()

Tags: c#, .net, excel

C# .net framework 2.

В третьем фреймворке есть метод

```
protected internal virtual FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileDownloadName);
```

Какой есть аналог во втором фреймворке?
Мне нужно вернуть файл excel на основе байтового потока.

Пытаюсь разобраться с библиотекой http://npoi.codeplex.com/ для экспорта данных в excel.
Файл Excel читается без проблем, а вот дальше... Когда записываю memoryStream в виде массива в Response, он ,насколько я понимаю, конвертится в строку и на выходе получается текстовый файл с содержимым "System.Byte[]".

Код:

```
FileStream fs =
                new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/templates/template.xls"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            // Getting the complete workbook...
            HSSFWorkbook templateWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fs, true);

            // Getting the worksheet by its name...
            var sheet = templateWorkbook.GetSheet("Sheet1");

            // Getting the row... 0 is the first row.
            var dataRow = sheet.GetRow(4);

            // Setting the value 77 at row 5 column 1
            dataRow.GetCell(0).SetCellValue(77);

            // Forcing formula recalculation...
            sheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation = true;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            // Writing the workbook content to the FileStream...
            templateWorkbook.Write(ms);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.BufferOutput = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                                 string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "export"));
            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            Response.Charset = "utf-8";
            Response.Write(ms.ToArray());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.`[`BinaryWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)`(ms.`[`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)`);`

Comment: Спасибо, так действительно работает)