# List<TResult> To XML FileResult

Tags: xml

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как я могу предоставить пользователю загрузку файла из приложения ASP .Net MVC, путем конвертации из List* в FileResult с расширением .xml.

```
List<Gpx> Gpx = new List<Gpx>();
        if (geometry!=null && geometry.Any())
        {
            List<Rte> rte = new List<Rte>();
            var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss");                
            foreach (var i in geometry)
            {   
                string name = i.properties.title;
                List<Wpt> wpt = new List<Wpt>();
                List<Rtept> rtept = new List<Rtept>();
                rte.Add(new Rte
                {
                    Desc = name,
                    Name = name,
                    Number = "1"                        
                });
                int p = 0;
                foreach (var c in i.geometry.coordinates)
                {
                    long timedev = i.properties.time[p];
                    var lat = c[0];
                    var lon = c[1];

                    wpt.Add(new Wpt
                    {
                        Lat = lat.ToString(),
                        Lon = lon.ToString(),
                        Ele = name,
                        Time = timedev.ToString(),
                        Desc = $"<![CDATA[{name}]]>",
                        Sym = "Dot"
                    });
                    rtept.Add(new Rtept
                    {
                        Lat = lat.ToString(),
                        Lon = lon.ToString(),
                        Ele = name,
                        Time = timedev.ToString(),
                        Desc = $"<![CDATA[{name}]]>",
                        Sym = "Dot",
                        Type = "<![CDATA[Dot]]>"
                    });

                    p =p+1;
                }
                Gpx.Add(new ApiController.Gpx
                {
                    Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss"),
                    Creator = "Creator",
                    Xmlns = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0",
                    Xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                    Version = "1.0",
                    SchemaLocation  = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd",
                    Rte = new Rte
                    {
                        Desc = name,
                        Name = name,
                        Number = "1",
                        Rtept = rtept
                    },
                    Wpt = wpt
                });
            }
        }
```

На выходе, получаю структуру документа для XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.0" creator="Сreator" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
<time>2002-02-27T17:18:33Z</time>
<wpt lat="42.438878" lon="-71.119277">
 <ele>44.586548</ele>
 <time>2001-11-28T21:05:28Z</time>
 <name>5066</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[5066]]></desc>
 <sym>Crossing</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Crossing]]></type>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="42.439227" lon="-71.119689">
 <ele>57.607200</ele>
 <time>2001-06-02T03:26:55Z</time>
 <name>5067</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[5067]]></desc>
 <sym>Dot</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Intersection]]></type>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="42.438917" lon="-71.116146">
 <ele>44.826904</ele>
 <time>2001-11-16T23:03:38Z</time>
 <name>5096</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[5096]]></desc>
 <sym>Dot</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Dot]]></type>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="42.443904" lon="-71.122044">
 <ele>50.594727</ele>
 <time>2001-11-28T21:05:28Z</time>
 <name>5142</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[5142]]></desc>
 <sym>Dot</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Dot]]></type>
</wpt>
<rte>
 <name>BELLEVUE</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[Bike Loop Bellevue]]></desc>
 <number>1</number>
<rtept lat="42.430950" lon="-71.107628">
 <ele>23.469600</ele>
 <time>2001-06-02T00:18:15Z</time>
 <name>BELLEVUE</name>
 <cmt>BELLEVUE</cmt>
 <desc><![CDATA[Bellevue Parking Lot]]></desc>
 <sym>Parking Area</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Parking]]></type>
</rtept>
<rtept lat="42.431240" lon="-71.109236">
 <ele>26.561890</ele>
 <time>2001-11-07T23:53:41Z</time>
 <name>GATE6</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[Gate 6]]></desc>
 <sym>Trailhead</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Trail Head]]></type>
</rtept>
<rtept lat="42.434980" lon="-71.109942">
 <ele>45.307495</ele>
 <time>2001-11-07T23:53:41Z</time>
 <name>PANTHRCAVE</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[Panther Cave]]></desc>
 <sym>Tunnel</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Tunnel]]></type>
</rtept>
<rtept lat="42.436757" lon="-71.113223">
 <ele>37.616943</ele>
 <time>2001-11-28T21:05:28Z</time>
 <name>6014MEADOW</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[6014MEADOW]]></desc>
 <sym>Dot</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Dot]]></type>
</rtept>
<rtept lat="42.439018" lon="-71.114456">
 <ele>56.388000</ele>
 <time>2001-06-02T03:26:55Z</time>
 <name>6006</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[600698]]></desc>
 <sym>Dot</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Intersection]]></type>
</rtept>
<rtept lat="42.438594" lon="-71.114803">
 <ele>46.028564</ele>
 <time>2001-11-28T21:05:28Z</time>
 <name>6006BLUE</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[6006BLUE]]></desc>
 <sym>Dot</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Dot]]></type>
</rtept>
<rtept lat="42.438917" lon="-71.116146">
 <ele>44.826904</ele>
 <time>2001-11-16T23:03:38Z</time>
 <name>5096</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[5096]]></desc>
 <sym>Dot</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Dot]]></type>
</rtept>
<rtept lat="42.438878" lon="-71.119277">
 <ele>44.586548</ele>
 <time>2001-11-28T21:05:28Z</time>
 <name>5066</name>
 <desc><![CDATA[5066]]></desc>
 <sym>Crossing</sym>
 <type><![CDATA[Crossing]]></type>
</rtept>
</rte>
</gpx>
```

Дело в том, что не могу понять, есть ли способ перевода в XML и вернуть response с сервера, как файл с расширением XML?

Comment: Ваш вопрос сводится к другому вопросу - как выгрузить файл.

Comment: Вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660116/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-asp-net/ Response всегда можно взять из System.Net.HttpContext.Current.Response (это отличие от ASP)

Comment: Возможно и так, задача заключается в сохранении List<TResult> в XML file

Comment: Файл вы получили? Осталось выгрузить? Или не получается сделать XML?

Comment: **Server.MapPath** - подразумевает то, что файл предварительно сохраняется на сервере. А можно ли сделать перевод листа в буферный поток и из потока выполнить сохранение?

Comment: Да. Всё то же, только `Response.Write` вместо MapPath

Comment: Файл не удается получить. Т.к. не знаю следующие шаги, что сделать с готовым List`ом.

Comment: Вот ещё пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145760/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-filecontentresult-file

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Добавьте необходимые теги в вопрос: язык программирования (очевидно, C#), технология (ASP.NET MVC или MVC Core или, может, у вас WebAPI?), платформа (.NET или .NET Core).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за подсказки, решение следующее:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Gpx>));
            using (var stream = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, gpx);
                var t = stream.ToString();
                Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                Response.Write(t);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment;filename=GPX_{GlobalName}_{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}.xml");
                Response.End();
            }
```